# How to apply animation to different objects

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a cupboard with 9 boxes. On one of them I have animation, which open / close box. It is only change **X** coordinate of the box, but I can't apply this animation to another boxes, because animation will move it to the coordinate of the first box.

In the debug mode parameter **Keep Original Position XZ** are disabled. Can't understand, what is wrong.

Should I create 9 similar animations for 9 boxes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is possible to animate stuffs using relative positions on the UI when using the anchors, but there does not seem to be any clean solution for 3D objects... [This post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784567/how-to-make-animation-position-start-from-last-pos.html) offers what seem to be the "best" solution for now (it uses an empty parent transform to move the animated object correctly...)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply the animation to any object.  I would recommend making a prefab of the "box" with the animation attached, then using the prefab for each.  Honestly I don't have much experience with animations of 3D objects, but even my 2D animations are in a 3D space, and each object animates properly with the same animations individually regardless of their location.